# Accute accent in flat file PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I have a file which has 4500 records , few records has accute accent ..each record has length of 2600..when i process that file say record 1000 has two accute accents in that case V_newline brings only 2598 ignoring those accute accents ..this is happening when i use ANSI format UTF8 working fine..system  pulling the file from FTP ..FTP gets file from mainframe..for testing I'm keeping file in my local windows machine
How to solve this..

**v_filehandle := utl_file.fopen ( p_filedir,v_filename,'r',5000 ) ;
LOOP
      BEGIN
        utl_file.get_line(v_filehandle,v_newline);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_line '||v_newline);****
.....